# HTTP interceptor in React to add token

Tags: react-oidc

I need to add the access token to HTTP requests.

My approach is to use `useEffect` to listen for changes in the `auth` object and respond by setting up an axios interceptor -- and removing a previos interceptor if there was one (because the token value it had will have expired).

```
import { InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import { AuthContextProps, useAuth } from "react-oidc-context";
import { AXIOS_INSTANCE } from "./api_mutator";
import { AppSettings, useAppSettings } from "./appSettings";

export const ApiContext: Context<null | string> = createContext<null | string>(null)

export const ApiProvider: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] }> = ({ children }) => {
    let appSettings: null | AppSettings = useAppSettings();
    let auth: AuthContextProps = useAuth();

    const [access_token, setAccesToken] = useState<null | string>(null)
    const [axiosInterceptorId, setAxiosInterceptorId] = useState<null | number>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ApiProvider.useEffect'); // This stops lots of refreshing.

        if (axiosInterceptorId) {
            AXIOS_INSTANCE.interceptors.request.eject(axiosInterceptorId);
        }

        let new_access_token: string | null = null;
        if (((appSettings?.apiBaseUrl?? '') !== '') && (auth?.isAuthenticated ?? false) && auth.user?.access_token) {
            new_access_token = auth.user.access_token;
            setAccesToken(new_access_token);
        }

        if (new_access_token) {
            // We're good: set up the interceptor.
            const interceptorId: number = AXIOS_INSTANCE.interceptors.request.use((config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>) => {
                return {
                    ...config,
                    baseURL: appSettings!.truthPortalApi!,
                    headers: auth.user!.access_token!
                        ? {
                            ...config.headers,
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.user!.access_token!}`,
                        }
                        : config.headers,
                } as InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>;
            });
            setAxiosInterceptorId(interceptorId);
        }
        else {
            setAxiosInterceptorId(null);
        }

    }, [appSettings, auth]);

    return (
        <ApiContext.Provider value={access_token}>
            {children}
        </ApiContext.Provider>
    )
}

// Hook for consumers to know whether the API is available.
export function useApi(): boolean {
    let at: string | null = useContext(ApiContext);
    return at != null && at !== '';
}
```

The first problem is that this causes hundreds of page reloads. I found that I could stop this by adding the `console.log`.

I've been told that I don't need to `useEffect` -- but not why it's unnecessary or what to do instead.
I believe that I need to `useEffect` beause I need to listen for changes in the `auth` object -- otherwise I'd only see its initial value and I'd never see an updated token.

If I run the code as part of the function componenent and not inside `useEffect` then the screen goes white and I get the *infinite loop* error.

What's going on?!